# python pandas separate 'merged' excel data into workbooks by Column Values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]

I'm trying to split the merged cell named `'aw'` by values into seperate workbooks.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file_path = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

for value in split_values :
    df1 = df[df['name'] == value ]
    output_file_name = "name_" + str(value) + "_trainings.xlsx"
    df1.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False)
```

but there is a key error. 
How can I split the `'aw'` values into different workbooks?
The different workbooks should contain the data above the `dataframe ( data frame, 1. name 3. data)`
and also the `function(sum)` the bottom of the dataframe.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Mentioning error message can help to understand your problem better.

Comment: packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'aw'